Why does the PID reported in a dmesg log message differ from that returned by os.getpid() in Python?
When debugging an OOM error in a Python multiprocessing script I noticed that a dmesg log will report
[Mon Jun 17 15:26:04 2024] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process **1079355** (python3) total-vm:5323820kB, anon-rss:5249840kB, file-rss:3392kB, shmem-rss:8kB, UID:0 pgtables:10448kB oom_score_adj:-997

Whereas each of the processes as reported by os.getpid() is in the range 471-475.
I'll note that this is being run in a container on a kubernetes pod.
Why the difference in process ids?

The PID in the error seems to be related to the cgroup of the running container rather than the app itself. The pod is running out of memory, not the app.

Containers have their own process namespace. A given process can and will have a different PID inside the container than it has on the host; dmesg is showing you the host PID, not the container PID (otherwise it would be ambiguous, as several different containers could all have a process locally numbered as 471).

(Voting to close as off-topic: this is more a sysadmin question for [unix.se] than a Python/development matter, as it's not in any way specific to the Python language, to multiprocessing, or for that matter to people writing software as opposed to troubleshooting an OOM from code someone else wrote).
